# Center a 17x11 paper using Horizontal

Tags: c++

```
#include "Calculator.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include "DoWhileLoops.h"
#include "Average.h"
#include "SwitchStatement.h"
#include "LogicalOperators.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include "RandomNumberGenerator.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctime>
#include "DefaultArguments.h"
#include "FindingCenter.h"

using namespace std;

int length;
int width;

int Horizontal(int length, int width);

FindingCenter::FindingCenter()


{
cout << Horizontal();

cout << "What is the length?" << endl;
cin >> length;
cout << "What is the width?" << endl;
cin >> width;

}
int Horizontal(int length, int width)
{
return ((17-(length + width))/ 3);
}
```

I keep getting this error:

```
"too few arguments to function 'int Horizontal(int, int)"
```

the code is for my own personal use im trying to center a 17x11 paper.
its an orthographic projection paper for my mechanical drawing class... also any other pointers will help thx :)

Comment: The error is very clear, you're calling `Horizontal` with no arguments when exactly 2 are needed.

Comment: It's also unclear what you want to do with Horizontal(), as you haven't supplied any arguments. Perhaps, you wanted the user to input and then print out Horizonal(length, width)? My code for this is here: https://ideone.com/0IgEi3

Answer (score 2):

The error is pretty clear: you are calling `Horizontal` with less than the required 2 arguments: in fact, you are calling it with *no* arguments.

Shouldn't you be calling it *after* you've read in `length` and `width`, so you can pass them to it?